# Does blinking an LED with no resistor for a few seconds harm my Arduino?

Tags: led, resistor

I am new to Arduino and I just made my first LED blink. I connected the LED to ground and digital pin 13 without resistance (for only a few seconds). Does this harm my Arduino?

Hilmi

Answer (score 2):

If you try it again with the proper resistor in place, and the pin still works, then no, you probably haven't damaged it. It may have stressed the pin driver some but if it passes the above test, I think you're still good to go.